# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sum' referenced before assignment odoo10

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I tried to calculate sum using python built-in function, bu getting above error.
***.py**

```
def _total_sum(self):
    stock_quant_ids = self.env['stock.quant'].search([('product_id','=',product.id)])
    inventory_value = (sum(line.inventory_value for line in stock_quant_ids))
```

How can resolve this issue?

Comment: You used `sum` as a variable name somewhere. Don't do that.

Comment: Why not a proper answer ? I'm still finding this question in the unanswered list and got here.

Comment: @majikat, in my function i had declared `sum =0.0`, thats why i got that error. I renamed it to `total_sum`. Now error is gone. I think comment  of  `user2357112` is right answer.

Comment: I know it's the right answer. I'm just saying that it's a comment, not an answer. I'm looking for Odoo questions to answer and when I search for one, this one is marked unanswered so people may be drawn here only to find that the question has been already answered (in a comment). I just ask for someone to write the answer in the answer area.

Answer (score -1):

As @user2357112 mentioned in the comments on the question you mustn't use built-in function names for variables.

Comment: That's a terrible way to test whether something is a built-in. It won't register names you've already stomped on, or things like `list`.

Comment: @user2357112: You are right of course. I didn't mean it to be a general test for built-in functions but as a proof that sum is one (since the OP commented '(...) I think [yours] is [the] right answer.'). Therefore I didn't think of lists and assigning something to sum and then testing it. Since it caused confusion I'll remove that part. Thanks for the heads-up!